# why this sql used union all returned no data

Tags: sql, oracle, union

the result of sql 1st:

```
select p1.t1, p2.t2, p2.t3 from 
(select 'A' as t1,'' as t2,'' as t3 from dual ) p1 left join
(select '' as t1, '' as t2, '' as t3 from dual where 1=2) p2 on p1.t1 = p2.t1
```

is

```
A   NULL    NULL
```

the result of sql 2nd:

```
select p1.t1, p2.t2, p2.t3 from 
(select 'B' as t1,'' as t2,'' as t3 from dual ) p1 left join
(select '' as t1, '' as t2, '' as t3 from dual where 1=2) p2 on p1.t1 = p2.t1
```

is

```
B   NULL    NULL
```

if I union all these two part of sql, my expected sql are:

```
A    NULL    NULL
B    NULL    NULL
```

but I get no result .

the sql is like below:

```
select p1.t1, p2.t2, p2.t3 from 
(select 'A' as t1,'' as t2,'' as t3 from dual ) p1 left join
(select '' as t1, '' as t2, '' as t3 from dual where 1=2) p2 on p1.t1 = p2.t1
union all
select p1.t1, p2.t2, p2.t3 from 
(select 'B' as t1,'' as t2,'' as t3 from dual ) p1 left join
(select '' as t1, '' as t2, '' as t3 from dual where 1=2) p2 on p1.t1 = p2.t1
```

I tested this sql on oracle.
I want to know why the result is not like my expected.
by the way, if use union instead of union all, the result is just like expected.

Comment: This is very odd behavior and confirmed on SQL Fiddle, at least, http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27926.

Comment: I see no reason for this to happen. It works on my dbms (Ora 10g). What version are you using?

Comment: I get the correct result in Oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0

Comment: I've tested this sql on my company's oracle, I got no result after excuted. I haven't paid attention on the version. I will have a look on the version Tomorrow.

Comment: Actually， I was writing a sql to query some business data, the sql is complex， and I find this problem, so I wrote this simple sql to simulate the complex one. I will take a look about the version of my company's oracle.thanks for all of you.thanks for Gordon Linoff , I have just know the sqlfiddle, it's amazing.

Comment: Possibly bug 12336962, if you are on 11.2.0.2 (as SQL Fiddle is)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't said which version you're encountering this on, but Gordon Linoff reproduced on SQL Fiddle which is running 11.2.0.2, and as others have said it's not seen in 10g and 11.2.0.3, so it seems reasonable to think you might be on 11.2.0.2 as well.

In which case, this looks identical to bug 12336962. If you have access to Oracle Support you (or your DBA) can look that up, but I can't reproduce what it says here, even though it's a published bug. Running your query and the example from the bug report produce the same results, and in both cases changing from `union all` to `union` produces correct results. You might want to raise a service request to get that confirmed though.

That bug is fixed in the 11.2.0.3 patch set - I'm not sure I'm really supposed to even share that, [but it's already published here](http://www.eygle.com/Notes/11.2.0.3.html) - so patching up might be your best bet, and Oracle might suggest that if you do raise an SR. If in doubt, ask Oracle directly.

Comment: the version is 11g (11.2.0.1.0), I agree with your opinion.